# Notification not displaying supplied image

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to show a notification using an image I receive over a socket as an arrayBuffer. The notification shows, but without the image supplied. The standard firefox logo/icon is used instead. Any help would be appreciated. The code seems to run without any errors, or rather, no errors are are thrown/stack trace printed when the notification is created.

Here is the code to create the notification:

```
ps_worker.port.on("notification", function(notification){
            //DISPLAY LINK TO USER
            var arrayBuffer_icon = notification.icon;
            var arrayBuffer_largeicon = notification.largeicon;

            var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arrayBuffer_icon);
            var base64String = utils.btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g,'$&\n');
            var dataUri = "data:image/png;base64,"+ base64String;

            notifications.notify({
                    title: notification.app + ": " + notification.title,
                    text: notification["subject"] + "\n" + notification.content,
                    data: "did gyre and gimble in the wabe", // data is a string passed through to the on click listener
                    iconURL: dataUri,
                    onClick: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                    }
            });
    });
```

the utils.btoa call is implemented as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Unit_testing

The relevant server code is (node.js):

```
function send_notification_to_socket(user, notification, target){
fs.readFile(notification.iconpath, function(err, buf){
        if(socketstore.get_socket_by_id(user)){
                socket = socketstore.get_socket_by_id(user);
                notification["icon"] = buf;
                socket.emit('notification', notification);
        }else{
                console.log("No socket for user " + user);
        }
});
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `port` API even capable of transmitting messages containing ArrayBuffers? Did you check that? Also `.replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g,'$&\n')`: Why?! Did you log your data URI and paste it in a tab to see if the regular browser can even process/decode it?

Comment: > Is the port API even capable of transmitting messages containing ArrayBuffers? Good point. This is probably where the error stems from.

Comment: Solved by just sending over base64 strings instead of arrayBuffers.

Comment: Care to make this into an answer?